# Grep Pattern matching- underline

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I've not been able to find anything online to help so hoping someone may have an idea.

What does an underline in an expression mean when using grep?

For example: [_a-zA-Z0-9]

Could someone help to explain the purpose here?

Comment: it is one possible character. So the Expression matchens underline, lower case charchter, upper case character and numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `grep` command uses a regular expression as it is also described in the [manpage of grep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep):

> A regular expression is a pattern that describes a set of strings. Regular expressions are constructed analogously to arithmetic expressions, by using various operators to combine smaller expressions.

A quick reference of the regular expression syntax can be found [here](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html). To test regular expressions with several input strings I recommend [regex101](https://regex101.com/).

---

The pattern `[_a-zA-Z0-9]` means to match a single character in the list. The list is opened with `[` and closed with `]`. The underscore (`_`) has no special meaning it is literally the underscore character. The minus character (`-`) means range, here from a to z (`a-z`) for example.

In short `[_a-zA-Z0-9]` means to match a single character wich is `_`, a character of the alphabet either lower or uppercase or a numerical character.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. What would be the difference between [A-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]* and [A-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9]* then?
Is it just that the former means the file or whatnot could have a '_' at the beginning and the other can't?
When I run the grep for both of these it lists all the directories and says 'xxx:is a directory'

Comment: `[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*` would expect the first character be `[A-Z]` and after that zero or more occurences of `[a-zA-Z0-9]` because of the star `*`. To your question: What is your whole command?

Comment: Hmm... It didn't put in the underscore in my comment above. There's an underscore in the first before the lowercase a, and in the second one there's one in the first brackets after the Z. So even with these I'm going to assume my interpretation was correct, as well as everyone's fantastic comments. 

Why would I be getting a list of directories even though I'm requesting to search within a text document?

Comment: What is your full command couldyou please describe it more accurate?

Comment: sure. It's grep [A-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]* q2        It gives me grep: Desktop: Is a Directory (plus others) as a result

Comment: And why Desktop shouldn't match?

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm just asking why it's coming up at all when I'm asking it to search in the text file named q2.

Comment: Sorry I've misread something... You're right it should search that pattern in a file called `q2` What is the content of `q2`? Another possibility would be to use: `cat q2 | grep [A-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*`